# Filtering a dataframe and isin worked but double-equals did not, why?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have two DataFrames, one called `dates` that contains "Observation dates" with the data type DateTime. The other being a DataFrame of hourly weather observations called `metar`.

This is what dates looks like:

```
In[6]: dates.head()
Out[6]: 
    ObservationDate
0   2021-09-11
1   2021-09-10
2   2021-09-05
3   2021-09-04
4   2021-09-03
```

The `metar` DataFrame is abit more full, but this is what the DateTime column will look like.

```
In[7]: metar['valid'].head()
Out[7]: 
0   2014-05-01 00:00:00
1   2014-05-01 01:00:00
2   2014-05-01 02:00:00
3   2014-05-01 03:00:00
4   2014-05-01 04:00:00
```

So you can see the second DataFrame has Year,Month,Day as well as the hour,min,sec. Meanwhile the first only has Year,Month,Day.

So what I would like to do is filter the second DataFrame using the dates in the first.

What I initially did was:

```
In[8]: filtered = metar[metar.valid.dt.strftime('%m%d') == dates.ObservationDate.dt.strftime('%m%d')]

Out[8]: ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

After some thinking I figured I would try the `isin` ability. Which actually worked, this is the snippet I wrote:

```
In[9]: filtered = metar[metar.valid.dt.strftime('%m%d').isin(dates.ObservationDate.dt.strftime('%m%d'))]
```

I am just wondering why the first attempt at filtering did not work but the second did.

Answer (score 1):

In the example using `isin`, you are looking for all of the values of `metar['valid']` that exist *anywhere* in `dates['ObservationDate`] (with the supplied formatting). That makes sense.

In the example using `==` you are looking for a all values in `metar['valid']` that are equivalent to the whole series `dates['ObservationDate']`. Pandas can't make sense of that unless, as it says, they have the same index, in which case it will compare the values of each series element-by-element.